# In what cases are the Enumerator objects (IE) and the Iterator objects (Fx) really useful?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

In what cases should I use those objects instead of an ordinary loop (if there are any such cases)?

Comment: Where are those "Iterator" and "Enumerator" objects specified? "Enumerator" appears to be an IE-exclusive, and "Iterator" is from Mozilla...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Yes, that's exact. I just thought it was quite obvious for someone who already has encountered those objects. Please be indulgent, it's my very first question in SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Enumerator Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ch9zb09%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) is usefull in server side javascript on a windows based system. You can use it to iterate a `Collection` that is returned by for example a method of the MS `FileSystemObject` or a `Collection` like `Request.QueryString`. You can't iterate through such collections directly using javascript (not with `for ... in`).

I'm under the impression that [Iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) are fairly new, not usable in all browsers and can be used to iterate through arrays, xml trees or ranges.